# Is there automatically way to update the linux-image-extra pkg after the kernel is update?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, docker

I am using ubuntu 16.04 on google cloud and sometime there is a kernel is updated that happen automatically .

I use this server for docker and when the kernel is updated then the docker service stops because of that .

Is there a way to cause the extra to be installed automatically each time the kernel is updated ? and not run the command :

```
sudo apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Best regards.

Comment: Did you have any luck finding a solution to this yet?

Comment: Not sure but I have use the " # Install the recommended package.
sudo apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual " and reboot the server and that help .

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you install `linux-generic` instead, you'll end up with `linux-image-extra` for your kernel version (it's a dependency), and it will automatically get updated with future kernel updates.

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-generic
```

(This information is based on the reply here:  https://askubuntu.com/a/896004/122097)