# How do I install drivers for the RTL8821CE Network Controller on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, hp, realtek-wireless

My Laptop (HP Laptop 14-ck1xxx) came with the **RTL8821CE Network Controller**. When I run `lspci | grep Network` I get:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

I‘m unable to get the Wi-Fi to work. What I did so far:

1. Download the repo at https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.
2. Unzip the file and rename the folder from `rtl8821ce-master` to `rtl8821ce`.
3. Run the following commands in the terminal:

   - `cd Downloads/rtl8821ce/`
   - `sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms`
   - `sudo m-a prepare`
   - `sudo ./dkms-install.sh`

Everything seemed to install and execute successfully. Then, I rebooted my laptop and made sure secure boot is disabled. However, Ubuntu still displays:

```
No Wi-Fi Adapter Found - make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged in and turned on
```

The command `uname -r` returns:

```
5.4.0-7634-generic
```

The command `sudo lshw -C network` returns:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: c4:65:16:08:52:bf
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.178.37 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff
```

What am I doing wrong? How can this be solved?

Comment: Have a look at my similar problem (and solution) in this post: [1261784](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261376/how-do-i-get-my-network-and-settings-back-in-20-04/1261784#1261784).

Comment: Some one installed it on Ubuntu 17.10. https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce You can give it a try.

Comment: Start with `sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms`. I am not sure it is quite up-to-date. There is a git repo with working drivers too. I answered it many times.

Comment: Does this show Secure Boot enabled? `mokutil --sb-state`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This fixed the No Wifi on my ASUS D509DA laptop, Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS:

First Ensure that you disable Secure Boot in the BIOS(See snip below)
NOTE: I did not have do Step C as I had already disabled Secure boot.

Then run

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

To see what adaptor you have and hence which dtiver to install:

```
sudo lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

read full details at this link for your specific driver, see snip from that page below
https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/realtek.html#ID6

------------ Snip -----------

> Realtek RTL8821CE chipset
> 6. Below you'll find a how-to for installing a driver, which should get your RTL8821CE chipset to work.
>
> Proceed like this:
>
> a. First establish temporary internet connection by other means.
>
> b. Launch a terminal window. (You can launch a terminal window like
> this: *Click*)
>
> c. Copy/paste the following command line into the terminal, in order
> to install the application mokutil and to let it examine the Secure
> Boot status of your machine:
>
> sudo apt-get install mokutil && mokutil --sb-state
>
> Press Enter. Type your password when prompted. In Ubuntu this remains
> entirely invisible, not even dots will show when you type it, that's
> normal. In Mint this has changed: you'll see asterisks when you type.
> Press Enter again.
>
> If it reports that Secure Boot is enabled: reboot and disable Secure
> Boot in the BIOS. In order to do this, you might need to set an
> administrator password in the BIOS first.
>
> Disabling Secure Boot is no loss: it adds no meaningful security
> anyway. It's primarily a means for Microsoft to enforce its vendor
> lock-in on your computer...
>
> d. Copy/paste the following command line into the terminal, in order
> to install the driver:
>
> sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms
>
> Press Enter.
>
> e. Reboot your computer. Your WiFi card should work now. If not: try
> the rtw88 driver, as described in item 7 below.

--------- end snip -----------

Comment: Why would we disable the Secure Boot if the package is stated as `dkms` package?

Comment: Because Some DKMS modules need to be configured properly to work with UEFI Secure Boot - see: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS

Answer (score 3):

I used my phone as an USB modem and installed dkms.
`apt update && apt install -y dkms`

After this, I went to Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers
and just enable Realtek 8821 driver.

Then I rebooted my laptop and voila, WIFI does work.

Answer (score 1):

[@Vik's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1268534/354327) is correct, but I'd like to add a little procedure for the cases where you can't connect the affected box to the Internet. For example, the Chuwi Hi10 X tablet has this RTL8821CE WiFi module and no other network device. In this case I used another Ubuntu 20.04 box to download the packages using:

1. `sudo apt download rtl8821ce-dkms` to download the kernel module package
2. `sudo apt download $(apt depends rtl8821ce-dkms | grep Depends: | cut -d ' ' -f 4)` to download it's dependencies

Then copied all the downloaded deb packages from `/var/cache/apt/archives` to an USB drive, and from the USB drive to the tablet, where I installed all of them using `dpkg -i *.deb`. For every package that failed to install I repeated step 2, downloading it's dependencies and copying them back to the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT need to disable secure boot since apt-get handles everything for you.  I installed the driver under Lubuntu 20.04 with secure boot enabled.  Based on other posts, I ran

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential rtl8821ce-dkms`

During the 'apt-get install' process, the system installed the MOK certificates and prompted me for a password.  When it finished, I rebooted, selected 'Enroll MOK', entered the password, rebooted again, and it worked.