# No Wifi option in top right

Tags: networking, wireless

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, and when i look in the settings in the top right there is no WIFI option, I use a dual boot with Windows 10 where the WIFI works 100%

Edit: i started nm-applet and the settings now show, but i still don't know how to connect.

Edit 2: lspci shows this:

```
<snip>
07:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to install a dedicated firmware:

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Then restart your computer

See this previous post for more references https://askubuntu.com/a/1268534/1144685

If it's still not working, please post the output of the following command: `sudo iwconfig`