# Can we start ubuntu from an SD card?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, ssd, sd-card

I'm trying to do a workaround for someone else, the problem is the ssd of the laptop doesn't work and so I tried to install ubuntu from my USB into his SD card, the install went well but now it gets freezes in ubuntu start, any ideas? Is this a wrong logic?

**Edit:** I  could though access a tty and get into de system

The error reported by the system is:

Acpi error no handler for Region RCM0

**Edit 2:**

After 5 min waiting it did start but there is no wifi network detected (and there are several here.)

Running networkctl I can see there is no network card, if in not wrong as the output is:

Lo unmanaged
Enp2s0 unmanaged

And nothing else

**Edit 3** List of network pci:

- Ethernet controller
- network controller rtl8821ce 802.12 wireless network adapter

Comment: What version are you trying to install?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS @David

Comment: For future reference, you should always type the error in your question instead of posting a picture so we can easily google the error for more information. Posting a picture instead is a good way to get ignored so you're lucky the picture wasn't accepted.

Comment: Also, is this an ARM64 system?

Comment: How can I know that? It did boot but after long but still no Wii detected @mchid

Comment: @Minsky I think `uname -m` should show but I think the answer is the same either way so don't worry about it. I have posted an answer below. As for the wifi question, we only allow one question at a time so please open a separate question for the wifi issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Minsky Also, be sure to include the output of the following command in your question. `lspci | grep -i net`

Comment: I'm writing it now @mchid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an Asus, IBM, Lenovo, Panasonic, Sony, or Toshiba laptop run the following commands to possibly add proper ACPI support.

You will need to be connected to the internet so use an Ethernet connection if WIFI is not available.

**First**, install the `acpi-support` package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install acpi-support
```

**Next**, enable ACPI and update grub:

```
sudo sed -i 's/acpi=off //g' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

**Finally**, save any unsaved files and then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

If your problem is fixed, you are done. If not, you can follow the instructions to disable ACPI.

---

**If ACPI is causing a problem**, you can edit your command line kernel parameters in your `/etc/default/grub` file to disable ACPI<sup>1</sup>.

**First**, run the following command to automatically edit your grub configuration file.

```
sed -i 's/quiet splash/acpi=off &/' /etc/default/grub
```

**Then**, run the following command to update grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Finally**, reboot.

**<sub>1) note: If you disable ACPI on a laptop, check to make sure the fan is working properly. If you encounter any hardware issues, you can follow the instructions to re-enable ACPI.</sub>**

---

What this does is it edits the 11th line in your `/etc/default/grub` file from this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off quiet splash"
```

to disable the linux kernel ACPI option.

This should fix the problem if ACPI is incompatible.

[I found the answer to a similar issue here on unix.stackexchange.com.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/575101/how-to-fix-acpi-error-no-handler-for-region-ecrm-debian)

---

**If disabling ACPI causes issues**, you can re-enable ACPI by running the following commands.

```
sed -i 's/acpi=off //' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Save any unsaved files and then reboot and apply the changes:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Those disappeared, but still no network detected, I understand this is a different question. I've included details in the post.

Comment: @Minsky Also, make sure there aren't any issues like the fan not working with ACPI turned off. If you experience any hardware issues, you can always enable ACPI and reboot. Actually, the error may be of no consequence but [there is currently a bug filed for this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1872261). As for your wifi, it looks like you might have to use the ethernet adapter to connect to the internet and then install a driver for your rtl8821ce wifi card. [I found the answer for your wifi card here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1268534/167115).

Comment: @Minsky Also, I added some extra instructions which may provide proper ACPI support.