# Unable to install drivers with an Internet connection

Tags: drivers, server, wireless, internet, lenovo

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad S145-15AST with a Fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS.
It has no Ethernet port and doesn't have WiFi drivers. I'm trying to install WiFi Drivers for the Realtek RTL8821CE, but all of the ones I've seen require you to either wire into an ethernet port or use USB Tethering on an Android device. The first one I can't do for obvious reasons, and the second one I can't do because my Provider disables USB Tethering. I tried installing the drivers off apt on another machine and pulling the .deb files from /var/cache/apt/archive onto a USB Drive, and installing it there, but to no avail.
I have an Internet connection on other machines, just not that one.
Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this? [How do I install drivers for the RTL8821CE Network Controller on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261902/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-rtl8821ce-network-controller-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: That one requires me to install packages via apt and I can't do that since I don't have an Internet connection on that device.

Comment: "*but to no avail*" is too vague to offer useful advice. If you can't/won't sneakernet the packages across from an online system, then you must (obviously) find a friend with a better data plan or borrow a friend's working wireless USB dongle. There is no magic setting that makes unsupported wifi hardware suddenly work.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. I'll try to be more specific next time. However, now that you mentioned it, I have a USB WiFi Antenna lying around the house somewhere. I'll find that and then give that a try. I'll update when I get there.