# No wifi device detected not even with `ip addr`

Tags: networking, wireless, 21.10

This seems to be a common issue but none of the resolutions I found on this forum seems to address my specific experience.

I did fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10 on an ASUS Vivobook (used to be a Windows machine but I replaced the entire Windows partition) but my wifi was not detected.  Please see outputs below:

```
sudo lshw -class network -short

H/W path       Device     Class       Description
=================================================
/0/100/1c.5/0             network     RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

```
ip addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The former suggest there is a wifi adapter while the latter suggest there is not.  All the posts I have come across assumes that there is some `wlp3s0` or other available in the `ip addr` call yet I have none such.

Comment: is this working? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261902/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-rtl8821ce-network-controller-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Not really, my challenge here is to "find other means to connect to the internet".  This notebook does not have a wired network card and I am not able to connect via a hotspot via phone.  This seems to be the issue I would need to resolve first...

Comment: Do you have access to an internet-connected system that can share some media, e.g. USB disk, with your Vivobook?

Comment: Yes.  I have plenty of machines on the net.  Just not that one.

Comment: You probably need to install a RTL8821CE driver. Go to https://github.com and search for RTL8821CE. You'll need to download it to a USB flash drive and carry it over. There are other dependencies that may need to be installed to compile this... like **build-essential** and **dkms**.

Comment: This is just an FYI: Get an RJ45 (ethernet) to USB adapter. It plugs into your USB and has an ethernet jack on the other end. I've yet to find one that didn't work with Linux. This means you can temporarily connect via wired internet to grab wireless drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.  Got myself an usb ethernet adapter as suggested by @KGill and installed `rtl8821ce-dkms` as pointed to by @nobody above.  All good after restart.  Wifi up and running.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Buying newer hardware isn't an appropriate solution.

Comment: Agreed. But ultimately the issue was connectivity.  The actual driver problem has been discussed and solved in previous posts which only left connectivity.  And that could only be solved through somehow making that connection.  In all fairness, this post is then mute and could be removed totally since I agree it does not really add value to thsi form.